# Reactjs how to call magento 2 api with bearer (the server responded with a status of 401 (unauthorized))

Tags: reactjs, magento2

I'm try to use reactjs (from localhost:80) to call (http://m2.example.com:80) magento 2 api, but it only return Error: the server responded with a status of 401 (unauthorized)"

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://m2.example.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=20",{
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer 3nsi1y7pcun1atvhs87dxmokymquofii', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.name}>
              {item.name} {item.price}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}
/*const App = () => (
   <div>
     <h1>Hello world!!</h1>
   </div>
   )*/

   
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById("root"));
//ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root1"));
```

Anyone know what's wrong with above code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @kiranvj i tested with postman with same token but not work in reactjs

Comment: seems like the headers didn't send?

Comment: @kiranvj tried, not work, i added a image showing the console

Comment: i saw if add  mode: 'no-cors', the authorization headers will not being send

Comment: but if i remove no-cors, there is an other error : Access to fetch at 'http://m2.example.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=1' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: In that case I would suggest to remove `no-cors` and handle cors from the php.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287239/how-to-enable-cors-to-access-magento-rest-apis-magento2

Comment: sounds like a solution, i will test it later

Comment: @kiranvj you can add the comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `mode: 'no-cors'` and `'withCredentials: true'` and handle CORS from the backend php magento2 - Please check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287239/how-to-enable-cors-to-access-magento-rest-apis-magento2) on how to do it

```
fetch("http://m2.example.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=20",{
        method: 'GET',           
        credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer 3nsi1y7pcun1atvhs87dxmokymquofii', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
```

After that it should work.